# How find this sum $\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{2}{3^2}+\frac{3}{4^2}+\frac{2}{5^2}+\frac{4}{6^2}+\cdots+\frac{d(n)}{n^2}+\cdots$

Tags: analysis, summation

**Question:**

> Find the value
>   $$\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{2}{2^2}+\dfrac{2}{3^2}+\dfrac{3}{4^2}+\dfrac{2}{5^2}+\dfrac{4}{6^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{d(n)}{n^2}+\cdots$$

where $d(n)$ is The total number of positive divisors of $n$

I think we can use 
$$\zeta{(2)}=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\cdots=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$

I know If the prime factorization of  is given by

$$n=p^{a_{1}}_{1}\cdot p^{a_{2}}_{2}\cdots p^{a_{n}}_{n}$$

then the number of positive divisors of  is
$$d(n)=(a_{1}+1)(a_{2}+1)\cdots(a_{n}+1)$$

But follow is very ugly,I don't understand @Nate idea(my English is poor),can you post detail? Thank you

Comment: What other tools do you have to hand?  Do you know about multiplicative functions?  Do you know Euler's product formula(s)?

Comment: Consider the sum of the squares of the reciprocals of all numbers divisible by 1, the sum of the squares of the reciprocals of all numbers divisible by 2, the sum of the squares of the reciprocals of all numbers divisible by 3, the sum of the squares of the reciprocals of all numbers divisible by 4...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $d(n) = \sum_{d|n}1$ you can write
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{d(n)}{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Now, the set $\{ (d,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : d|n \}$ can be identified with the set $\{ (k, d)\in \mathbb{N}^2  \}$ by the map $(k,d) \mapsto (d, kd)$ (so $n = kd$). This means that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{n^2}=
\sum_{d=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(kd)^2} = 
\sum_{d=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{d^2} \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} \right)^2$$

Comment: Very Elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ be the list of primes and 
$\mathcal{E}$ be the collection of non-negative integer sequences
$( e_k )_{k\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}$ with finitely many non-zero terms.

Evey $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ can be represented as a product of the form
$\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{e_k}$ for an unique $e \in \mathcal{E}$.

We have
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}} \frac{d(n)}{n^2} 
= \sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} 
\frac{d\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{e_k}\right)}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{e_k}\right)^2}
= \sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e_k+1}{p_k^{2e^k}}
= \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \sum_{e_k=0}^\infty \frac{e_k+1}{p_k^{2e^k}} \right]\\
= \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{p_k^2}\right]^{-2}
= \left\{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{p_k^2}\right]^{-1}\right\}^2
= \left\{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{e_k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_k^{2^{e_k}}}\right\}^2\\
= \left\{\sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} 
\frac{1}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty p_k^{e_k}\right)^2}
\right\}^2
= \left\{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}}\frac{1}{n^2}\right\}^2
= \zeta(2)^2
= \frac{\pi^4}{36}
$$

Comment: Any explanations on how you manipulate?

Comment: @Alizter you basically break down every integer $n$ into its unique factorization of primes $n \mapsto p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots$. The exponents $e_k$ will be a sequence of non-negative numbers with finitely many non-zero terms. Sum over $n$ is equivalent to the sum over all possible combination of exponent $e_1, e_2, \ldots$. When you have summation of the form $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}}\frac{f(n)}{n^z}$ where $f(n)$ is multiplicative i.e $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ whenever $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. The sum becomes an infinite product over the corresponding prime factors.

Comment: You just figure out what happens to each prime factor and combine the result.